# Disable passwords in mail.log

Tags: dovecot

I'm running a postfix/dovecot/mysql mailserver.

In my /var/log/mail.log I can see my plain text password showing up:

```
dovecot: auth-worker(25749): pam(username@example.com,1.2.3.4,<FgaHxoXXdgCvy/>): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?) (given password:myPlaiNTextPassword)
```

Maybe it is not a big deal, but I don't feel comfortable with it.

How can I disable plaintext password entries showing up in /var/log/mail.log?

`dovecot -n`:

```
# 2.2.27 (c0f36b0): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.16 (fed8554)
# OS: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian 9.3 ext4
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
imap_id_send = name
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
  driver = static
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like?

Comment: I tried to search a solution online. I will post dovecot -n in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would toggle the values of:

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
```

Try with **no**, of course.

(Also, check password scheme. Right now it may be plain text. Try to use any kind of password hashing instead.)

Comment: After Milos suggestion, I edited /etc/dovecot.conf as follows:

auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_verbose = no
auth_verbose_passwords = no

After restarting dovecot service, no passwords are anymore shown in /var/log/mail.log. My question has been answered.

Comment: Also you can disable unnecessary logging after `dovecot` setup by adding directives `debug_log_path = /dev/null` and `info_log_path = /dev/null` to the each protocol section. This is not good explained feature that allow to reduce amount of logs and leave untouched only records about delivery and fails.

Comment: @kzpm post your comment about "no values" as an answer please! it was useful for me!